# xml.etree.ElementTree how can i add attribute inside of a node?

Tags: python, xml, xml-generation

I want the build an xml file and i made some research. I decided the use xml tree but i couldn't manage the use it like i want.

I want the generate this xml.

```
<Invoice test="how can i generate this ?">

</Invoice>
```

i am doing in python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as gfg


def GenerateXML(fileName):
    root = gfg.Element("Invoice")
    root.tail = 'test="how can i generate this ?"'
    tree = gfg.ElementTree(root)

    with open(fileName, "wb") as files:
        tree.write(files)
```

It's generate xml file look like:

```
<Invoice />test="how can i generate this ?"
```

I know i shouln't use tail for i want. But i can't find a way for the make a xml look like what i want. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of XML structure is called "attribute".
You can get it using the `set(attr, value)` method.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as gfg


def GenerateXML(fileName):
    root = gfg.Element("Invoice")
    root.set('test', 'how can i generate this ?')
    tree = gfg.ElementTree(root)

    with open(fileName, "wb") as files:
        tree.write(files)


GenerateXML('test.xml')
```

test.xml:

```xml
<Invoice test="how can i generate this ?" />
```